# How to stop boost asio io_service and finish all posted handlers?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Looks like the `io_service::stop()` only let the `run()` return. And the `io_service::~io_service` will destroy all the handlers.

Is there a way to let `io_service` finish all the queued handlers and then stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens automatically: `io_service::run` will automatically unblock once all work has been completed (and no new work is added). This is provided that you do not use an `io_service::work` object.